# Nested Venv possible in python 3? Is so can we able to access all the packages installed on all the venv?

Tags: python, conda, python-venv

I have activated the conda environment at first and then I have tried to activate the venv created by python3s' native virtualenv package without deactivating the conda environment. To my surprise both the venv are in running state. But python used by the venv is the one which I have activated recently. Can any one explain what is happening here ?

```
~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
~$ conda activate py369
(py369) ~$ which python
/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py369/bin/python
(py369) ~$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) (py369) ~$ which python
/home/xxx/venv/bin/python
(venv) (py369) ~$
```

If this is like both the venv's are activated then Am I able to access both the packages from conda env and also the venv?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening:

1. You activate the conda environment. `conda` then modifies your PATH such that `/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py369/bin` is first. You can check this with `echo $PATH`. It also modifies your shell prompt such that (py369) is displayed in front
2. You activate your virtualenv environment. Since virtualenv is oblivious of what `conda` does, it simply modifies your `PATH` such that `/home/xxx/venv/bin/` and puts its own prefix in front of your shell prompt

So now, when you call `python`, it will be started from the virtualenv folder. When you import packages, they will be loaded from what is installed inside your virtualenv. So you cannot just import from both the conda and virtualenv environment at the same time.

You also have not mentioned why you would want to have such a set up. My personal opinion is that you should not mix different environment programs, as it will only generate confusion.

Comment: Might also help to explicitly define the words "*activate*" and "*activated*", since this seems to be the confusion of OP. Namely, OP appears to be interpreting the resulting PS1 to indicate both environments are activated.